# Как вернуть стандартный Action Bar?

Tags: java, android

Использую фрагменты и в одном из фрагментом я подключаю кастомный actionbar но по завершению пользователем просмотра контента на одном фрагменте нужно вернуть стандартный actionbar. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```